# Git Submodule not reachable

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository that has a submodule. This git repository is mirrored in a separate environment as well. However, the submodule git repository is not mirrored. The two environments can't talk to each other. For the purpose of explaining the problem lets say `ENV1` has the submodule (`bar`) and the git repo (`foo`). `ENV2` is the mirror of the git repo (`foo`) and `bar` submodule isn't mirrored in `ENV2`

Problem I'm encountering is that in `ENV2`, although the `bar` directory is present...it is empty. This is because `ENV2` can't talk to `ENV1`. Is there any way to resolve this? My goal is to commit code **ONLY** in `ENV1`. Should I also put `bar` submodule on `ENV2` and start mirroring it? If so, how would the submodule URL change according to the environment. Meaning:

On `ENV1` I do:

```
git submodule add git@env1:group/bar.git
```

Would I have to explicitly add a different URL for `ENV2` like

```
git submodule add git@env2:group/bar.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submodule is an url+a SHA1 reference.

Your mirror will mirror the SHA1 reference (a gitlink, special entry in the parent Git repo, which is mirrored)

But since the submodule repo itself is not mirrored... the parent repo can reference a SHA1 which does not exist in the (non-mirrored) image bar submodule repo. (or if bar is not present at all in the mirror environment, it would be empty anyway for any SHA1)

The mirrored parent repo must have a way to reference an accessible and up-to-date bar repo.

Instead of trying to change it locally, check if a config like [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) would work: the goal would be to use `git@env2` insteadOf `git@env1`, but without changing the `git@env1` which is in the `.gitmodules`.

A `clone --recursive` or a `clone` followed by a `git submodule update --init` will then populate the `bar` submodule.

---

As a workaround, on Jenkins, you can:

- let Jenkins do the checkout (with bar empty)
- do as a first build step a `sed` on the `.gitmodules` to change the url of bar, as suggested by the [OP Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654203/anthony) below
- do a `git submodule update --init`

Comment: The prerequisite of this is to actually put the submodule on `env2` first, right?

Comment: Exactly, or the parent repo would not be able to checkout and access the submodule content.

Comment: I'm doing the following on `env2` but it doesn't seem to be taking an effect`git config --global url.ssh://git@env2.insteadOf ssh://git@env1`

Comment: @Anthony Do you mean a `git submodule update --init` still is trying to access `bar` subrepo as `git@env1`?

Comment: Yes. I run the `url.insteadof` as mentioned in comment above before running `git submodule update --init`. By doing that I expected that the submodule update --init will go to `git@env2` instead of `git@env1`

Comment: @Anthony that is what I hoped. What version of Git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: I am not sure of the OS because I run the above command from a `Jenkinsfile`. But the git version is `git version 1.8.3.1`: . If this won't work, I can use `sed` to modify the `.gitmodules` file prior to running submodule update --init

Comment: @Anthony OK makes sense: try Git 2.13.1, as git submodules have changed *a lot* since 1.8.3.1 (4 years ago, June 2013: https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v1.8.3.1)

Comment: @Anthony If you cannot upgrade, your workaround might work, and I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [Git modules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) explains:

> When cloning or pulling a repository containing submodules however, these will not be checked out by default; the `init` and `update` subcommands will maintain submodules checked out and at appropriate revision in your working tree.

On `ENV2` you have to run:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```